# Anaconda is not working in windows

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have installed python 3.x.On top of that if I install Anaconda then It's not working but when I uninstall Python 3.x then I install anaconda then It's working.What is the reason behind this scenario? I want to use machine learning library scikit-learn.Is there any way to install scikit-learn with all dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is certainly the best way. Do you start it using the Anaconda Navigator? What is the error message you get? Jupiter starts in a virtual environment, so you shouldn’t see that problem.

Comment: @giovnni Yes,I installed anaconda on top of pre-installed python but I get import error when I use machine learning libraries.Is there any way to create virtual-env in windows for a specific folder same like linux?

Comment: That’s not normal. Anaconda works on a virtual environment. Have you installed it from https://www.continuum.io/downloads and can you launch a jupiter notebook? Sklearn and many other packages come already with it.

Comment: Yes, I tried but when you install anaconda on top of installed python then it creates a problem.One solution to this problem is uninstall existing python and then install anaconda.it will work but I am looking for a solution without uninstalling python.How can I fix anaconda?

Comment: Ananconda installs the Python interpreter by default. In fact if you try to start Python from a CMD or a Terminal windows you will be able to do it with a version pointing to the conda virtual environment. So you should be fine to uninstall Python and Install Anaconda.